# Change cells background colour if array contains innerHTML

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to change those cells background colour that innerHTML values match with my array. How can i make it?

```
var numbers = ["15628","15623","15656","11628"];

var table = document.querySelector("[name='main']")
.contentWindow.document.getElementById("music").rows.length;

for (i = 4; i < table -1; i++){
    if (document.querySelector("[name='main']")
.contentWindow.document.getElementById("music").rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML == numbers)
    {
    document.querySelector("[name='main']")
.contentWindow.document.getElementById("music")
.rows[i].cells[1].style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    };
```

Comment: So question is "how to check if a value exists in an array"?

Comment: If i change the array to the correct string/number my code still not work. So i think there is a bigger problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this element select is correct: document.querySelector("[name='main']").contentWindow.document.getElementById("music").rows[i].cells[1] ?
It hard analize without looking to html.
If it OK, maybe you need such solution:

```
for (i = 4; i < table -1; i++){
    let value = document.querySelector("[name='main']")
.contentWindow.document.getElementById("music").rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML;

    if (numbers.includes(value))
    {
    document.querySelector("[name='main']")
.contentWindow.document.getElementById("music")
.rows[i].cells[1].style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    };
```